# Book where RPG characters are portrayed as real

Tags: story-identification, rpg, dungeons-and-dragons, centaurs

I'm looking for a Book where RPG characters are portrayed as real. Then at the end it shows that the RPGers are being played by another nested reality of RPGers and there is a bomb in the room.

Other random memories:

- One RPG character winds up wounded and with centaurs.
- An RPGer tries to scratch off a river hexagon with a butter knife but
  it refills.
- One RPGer tries to quit but his car won't start for him to leave.

I don't have much else. The cover was blue and showed a basket being lifted into the sky. And I keep googling game end etc. (it's not Ender's game!). I only remember those few scenes and that it's old (80s, maybe as late as 90-92 but I don't think so).

Comment: I'm assuming you are asking a story identification question.  We really need more details as this is a common trope.  You should check out this [checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/78394) and see if you can fill in some blanks for us.

Comment: Not the story you're looking for, but if you enjoyed a story like that, check out *NPCs* by Drew Hayes, and then the later books in the series.  (To say any more would be to drop massive spoilers, unfortunately.)

Comment: Caverns and Creatures has a real life to RPG plot but doesn't fit any of the other parameters: https://www.amazon.com/Critical-Failures-Caverns-Creatures-Book-ebook/dp/B0088XPHOK

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Gamearth by Kevin J.Anderson](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?15053). It is a trilogy and there is a (brief) [Wikipedia article describing the series here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamearth_Trilogy).

The scratching off a river hexagon is when they players are trying to remove it from a map:

> The hexagon of a lone village was inundated and changed without a trace. Melanie thought of the villagers, the people, their homes and fields.
> The River moved on until it emptied into the sea below.
> Melanie sat frozen. David turned gray.
> Scott jumped up and ran into the kitchen, pulling open drawers until he found the silverware. He came back to the map with a butterknife. He chipped away at one section of the new blue color.

As mentioned in a comment the cover is blue and does show a balloon basket:

[image: Gamearth cover]

You mentioned in a comment that you have been Googling *game end*, and indeed the last book of the trilogy is called [Game's End](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/807420.Game_s_End).

Comment: THAT'S The One! I srsly just heard the opening to Handle's Messiah when I read it!